# PHP: Run a mysql_query statement containing a string, but the string contains a string set in an included file that is called before the string is set

Tags: php, mysql, obfuscation

I have a PHP file included in the first line of my main PHP script like this:

```
// Include obfusctated MySQL queries
include "../../secure_storage/mysql_queries.php";

// $user_id stores the cookie as a variable. The cookie contains the user ID
$user_id = $_COOKIE['storerun_user_id'];

// Query the database to get the user's account information
$account_query = mysql_query($account_query_sql);
```

The included PHP file contains this line of code:

```
$account_query_sql = "SELECT `first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `password`, `referral_link`, `street_address`, `floor_apartment_number`, `notes`, `ecocash_number` FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = '$user_id'";
```

Reason being that I'm obfuscating SQL queries and placing them in a directory away from the root on the server.

The problem is that the included file contains an SQL query containing $user_id but the string is only set after the file is included. Any ideas on how to use my setup and be able to run the mysql_query? I've been trying to figure this out in my head all day on this. Surely there's a way to do this.

Comment: **Why are you obfuscating SQL Queries? Stop that.**

Comment: @Xatenev, to prevent a hacker from accessing the server via FTP and seeing the SQL statements for whatever reason.

Comment: 1. Don't use the deprecated `mysql_*`-functions. They are deprecated since PHP 5.5 and completely removed in PHP 7. Use MySQLi or PDO instead. 2. You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries, which can be used if you use the above mentioned MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: Set `$user_id = $_COOKIE['storerun_user_id'];` before the `include`?

Comment: @Dak Stop that now. Thats **hilarious**. **Secure your server instead of obfuscating server-side code.**

Comment: Getting the user id from a cookie and then use it in your query without any escaping seems very secure. :o

Comment: @Xatenev I have other variables like $user_id that are set later in the file. Before the include will work for $account_query to work, but I have other queries in the file.

Comment: @Dak So you obviously gotta retrieve all data first, before doing the SQL Queries. But like said before: **Stop obfuscating SQL Queries and secure your server instead**

Comment: The biggest security issue with database queries isn't if someone can see them, it's if someone can **manipulate** them (for example: SQL Injections which you are wide open for). If you use Prepared Statements, your queries wouldn't need to be concatenated with the data and this would be a non issue.

Comment: It's a pretty arse about face method @Dak, as a few have already said, mysql_* functions are deprecated, look toward PDO it's so much better to use and good practice!

Comment: PHP cannot time travel, therefore when you include your DB file and create your `$sql` string, `$user_id` doesn't exist (yet) and cannot be inserted into your query string.

Comment: This is an [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem. If you code it to best practices you don't even need an include to hide sql

Comment: @Xatenev I will secure the server.

Comment: @craig provided the answer I needed.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I am going to use your advice and switch to MySQLi and use prepared statements.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Dak, I wouldn't worry about hiding your sql queries.  However, if you do want to do this, one could add a string replace statement just prior to your query database statement and edit your included file to use 'search_item', e.g.:

```
str_replace('search_item', $user_id, $account_query_sql);
```

and included file would define $account_query_sql like below.

```
$account_query_sql = "SELECT `first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `password`, `referral_link`, `street_address`, `floor_apartment_number`, `notes`, `ecocash_number` FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = 'search_item'";
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks Craig. I'm taking no chances of any hacks whatsoever, that's why I was advised to hide SQL queries in case a hacker somehow accesses the root folder of the server via FTP.

Comment: Also known as foolish focus. If that is a problem you are probably toast anyway.

Comment: _"I'm taking no chances of any hacks whatsoever"_ - Really? This is a major hack, promoting a really bad practice, and not to mention, insecure!

Comment: Glad it worked.  Please do consider some of the advice provided in the comments, above, e.g. escape the cookie used in sql statement to avoid sql injection; don't use mysql statements, use mysqli; and, perhaps, reexamine your server security (no one should be gaining access to the root directory).

Comment: I've taken note of everyones comments. I've just escaped the cookies. I will switch to mysqli and prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the ordering of your code:

```
$user_id = $_COOKIE['storerun_user_id'];

include "../../secure_storage/mysql_queries.php";
```

PHP cannot time travel, therefore your code must perform the steps in the appropriate order - create your variables **BEFORE** you try to use them, not after.

And note that you are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: Craig's answer was exaclty what I need. Thanks for the tip about SQL injections, I'll work on that. Will do a full penetration and vulnerabilities test.

Comment: I suggest you pick a dozen queries sometime and let others review them.

Comment: Wrong attitude. If you send over a complete code base with every single query vulnerable to injection attacks, you're going to get smacked down. hard. Build secure code from the get-go. It's one thing to let a problem sneak through that you didn't know about. deliberately building vulnerable code is incompetence, plain and simple.

Comment: @Marc, he said that he would escape the cookies in comments above.